# Can i send string instead of json to MVC controller from ajax post?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am coming across an issue trying to send long strings of JSON to a MVC controller. First let me explain the need, then I will explain what I have tried. I  am preserving the HTML of the UI for a table into SQL. That way I can pull it back out and render it later. That being said, when I try to send from AJAX post to the controller, I keep getting the error that JSON max length has been hit.

What have I tried?

I have tried changing all settings in the web config and in the JSON `serializer` in the MVC controller to the `int.MaxLength` values. I have also changed my controller result to a content results instead of `JsonResult`. Here is some of the current code I use (stripped all unnecessary code and left what is needed for troubleshooting).

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts / updates a new saved quote template
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="jsonData"></param>
    public ActionResult SaveQuoteTemplate(string htmlTemplate, int totalRecords, int totalBadRecords, string templateName, string templateDescription, string templateNotes, string templateId)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };

        // For simplicity just use Int32's max value.
        // You could always read the value from the config section mentioned above.

        var returnData = new
        {
            StatusCodeEntity = ReturnCodeHandler.Status400,
            StatusMessage = "Unkown error occurred while trying to save the template.",
        };

        var resultSet = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = serializer.Serialize(returnData),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };

        try
        {
            JsonModel<QuoteEntitySavedItemVM> jsonModel = new JsonModel<QuoteEntitySavedItemVM>();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlTemplate))
            {

                string userPrefix = Session["LoginID"] != null ? Session["LoginID"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                QuoteEntitySavedItemVM qsvm = new QuoteEntitySavedItemVM()
                {
                    JSON = htmlTemplate,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Description = templateNotes,
                    TotalRecords = totalRecords,
                    TotalBadRecords = totalBadRecords,
                    Name = String.Format("{0} - {1}", userPrefix, templateName),
                    Id = QPortal.Web.Helpers.Utilities.SafeToInt32(templateId) //convert to int or safely returns 0 if null
                };

                qsvm.Id = _quoteEntityService.SavedQuoteTemplate(qsvm); //returns project id. So will now assign new on or same if update ran

                if (qsvm.Id == -1)
                {
                    var badReturn = new
                    {
                        StatusCodeEntity = ReturnCodeHandler.Status400,
                        StatusMessage = "There is already a project with this name. Please change name.",
                        ObjData = new List<QuoteEntitySavedItemVM>() { qsvm }
                    };

                    resultSet = new ContentResult
                    {
                        Content = serializer.Serialize(badReturn),
                        ContentType = "application/json"
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    var goodReturn = new
                    {
                        StatusCodeEntity = ReturnCodeHandler.Status200,
                        StatusMessage = "Project saved @" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".",
                        ObjData = new List<QuoteEntitySavedItemVM>() { qsvm }
                    };

                    resultSet = new ContentResult
                    {
                        Content = serializer.Serialize(goodReturn),
                        ContentType = "application/json"
                    };
}
            }
            else
            {
                var errorReturn = new
                {
                    StatusCodeEntity = ReturnCodeHandler.Status400,
                    StatusMessage = "Saving project failed due to submitted quote model to save being null. Please verify that you currently have a network connection or refresh page and try again."

                };

                resultSet = new ContentResult
                {
                    Content = serializer.Serialize(errorReturn),
                    ContentType = "application/json"
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var errorReturn = new
            {
                StatusCodeEntity = ReturnCodeHandler.Status500,
                StatusMessage = "An unknown error occurred while trying to save project. Please refresh page and try again. Details: " + e.Message

            };

            resultSet = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = serializer.Serialize(errorReturn),
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };
        }

        return resultSet;
    }
```

**View and JS snippet:**

```
//save project
    function saveQuoteTemplate() {
        var $templateBody = $("#quoteEntityItemsContainer"),
            url = '@Url.Action("SaveQuoteTemplate", "Home")',
            htmlTemplate = $templateBody.html(),
            totalRecords = $("#quoteEntityItemsContainer").find("tr").length,
            totalBadRecords = $("#quoteEntityItemsContainer").find("tr.table-danger").length,
            templateName = $("#txtTemplateNameLabel").text(),
            templateUserID = $("#txtUserID").text().trim(),
            templateNotes = $("#taNotes").val(),
            templateId = $("#txtTemplateNameLabel").attr("projectid"),
            data = { 'htmlTemplate': htmlTemplate, "totalRecords": totalRecords, "totalBadRecords": totalBadRecords, "templateName": templateUserID + templateName, "templateNotes": templateNotes, "templateId": templateId };



        updateProgressNotification('Saving project...');

        console.log("MAX LENGTH: 2097152 | 4MB default. This string length is:" + htmlTemplate.length);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ htmlTemplate, totalRecords, totalBadRecords, templateName, templateNotes, templateId }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            //Ajax evnts
            success: _saveQuoteTemplateSuccessHandler,
            error: _saveQuoteTemplateErrorHandler
        });

        $("#txtTemplateNameLabel").text(templateName);

        storeProjectTempData();
    }
```

What I am wondering, is how can I get around the max length issue that causes the failure server side before even hitting the controller, or can I change the JSON being sent to the controller, as just string param, string param2, and so on so it is not sent over as JSON?

Thanks much as always in advance!

Comment: Can you share the exact text of the error message?

Comment: I just realized, I wonder if it is parsing the depth of html and that is the limit being broken. I know in my debugger I will see for example, maxlength ~4MB and the string that breaks it is ~5MB. I wonder if I can parse the object I send to AJAX as json, but not parse the html property of the node also, and make that a string type? If there is no way around a hard limit, maybe I need to send multiple request and append them on the SQL side, though this seems very poor and clunky.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, here is how you can increase the sixe of a request body sent to the server.

`<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />` or

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; //50MB
});
```

see https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-asp-net-core/

Add [[FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) into your request action

```
public  ActionResult SaveQuoteTemplate([FromBody]string htmlTemplate, int totalRecords, int totalBadRecords, string templateName, string templateDescription, string templateNotes, string templateId) { ... }
```